# Lifting state alternative to call methods from other components

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am developing a mobile application with react-native (this is my first time using react by the way) and I'm having trouble communicating between components.

From my understanding react is meant to work from Parent to Children through props. Each component updates itself through its state and the parent through handlers binded in props. Still it doesn't feel right.

```
Parent (wrapper) component
|
|--AppBar Component
|
|--ListScrollView Component (displays API data fetched from the Parent)
|
|--FABmenu Component (handles the secondary components and provides callbacks to the Parent)
|
|--more secondary components (activity indicator, search bar, filtering modal etc)
```

The way I have implemented it is by placing all the business logic in the Parent Component and passing the Parent methods as props to the Children, but this setup proves to be chaotic in my usecase as new features are added daily and I need to go back and forth between the components to make everything work.

Redux/Flux don't actually provide a solution to this, they just override this behaviour with a global state for which you need to write more code (subscriptions) to update individual components.

Refs don't expose the whole component, just elements so that's not an option either.

I don't know about you but this makes my workflow extremely slow, I'd rather write methods to the component they (rationally) belong and call them statically. Am I missing something here or is this the sad truth?

Edit: Since I use expo, which doesn't ship with the latest react/react-native versions, I can't fully take advantage of the latest features (e.g. Context API). After some tinkering around I decided to use MobX, seems to do the trick.

Comment: If you find yourself prop drilling, [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) might clean things up here.

Comment: @go_diego damn I shouldn't skip that part of the documentation. Though it solves my immediate problem, Context is more of a workaround so I'll also redesign my structure. Going back to the whiteboard as we speak. Thank you all for your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an absolute rule that you must lift state up to the top-level parent component. You should lift state up as high as you can to avoid doing things multiple times.

For example, if you a Navbar component that needs to display a user's full name, you would do an API fetch for that data. But, let's say when you hit a Settings route, you *also* need the user's full name. Would it make sense to be hitting the API twice there? Once in the Navbar and once on the Settings component? Probably not!

But, you, as the architect of of your application are in charge of recognizing these opportunities and lifting state up where you can but it is not an absolute with React. It's a recommendation. If you find yourself doing a ton of unnecessary "prop plumbing" (i.e, passing props six component-levels down when only one component needs it), you may have lifted it too high.

There is nothing to my knowledge inside of React's architecture that forces you to do this. Solutions like Redux can help with, like you said, managing data flow and having a "global state" but they aren't the end-all-be-all and should NOT replace local state. There are still many cases and many opportunities to have business logic inside your components.

If that's the solution that works for you and for your application, go for it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to go through some basic constructs of writing an App in React.
Personally, I like the Container => Component way of arranging my App.

Integrating Redux, Router etc. are tedious stuff in React.

I followed this [workshop](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-workshop).

Moreover, follow this blog by [Dan Abramov](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-workshop)